# Auto Fill Text Boxes With Main Text Box Content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to auto-fill text boxes 1 to 3 with the main text box content so that whatever is typed into the text box "Title" will also appear in the text boxes
Input1, Input2 and Input3. Here is what I have, but I get an error.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyData(val){
     var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
     document.getElementById("CopyText").value=Title
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

Title:<input type="text" name ="Title" id="Text" onkeyup="CopyData(this)"/><br /> <br />
Input 1:<input type="text" name ="Input1" id="CopyText"/><br />
Input 2:<input type="text" name ="Input2" id="CopyText"/><br />
Input 3:<input type="text" name ="Input3" id="CopyText"/><br />                                                            

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please tell us which error you get. And: why do you use the same id for multiple elements?

Comment: Element `id` values have to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyData(val){
     var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
     var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
     for(var i=0;i < inputs.length;i++)
     {
       inputs[i].value = a;
     }

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

Title:<input type="text" name ="Title" id="Text" onkeyup="CopyData(this)"/><br /> <br />
Input 1:<input type="text" class="input" name ="Input1" /><br />
Input 2:<input type="text" class="input" name ="Input2" /><br />
Input 3:<input type="text" class="input" name ="Input3" /><br />                                                            

</body>
</html>
```

remarks:

1. do not use same id for multiple elements. try class instead
2. you use 'Title' which is not defined, use "a", that was where you stored the input's value
3. to get many elements at once with simple js, good method is to use "querySelectorAll" with the proper selector.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot assign the same id tag to more than one TextBox, so you must end up with a more "hard-coded" javascript function. Moreover, I would use Title.value and not only Title

```
function CopyData(){
 document.getElementById("CopyText1").value=Title.value;
 document.getElementById("CopyText2").value=Title.value;
 document.getElementById("CopyText3").value=Title.value;
}
```